# Вывод данных через цикл

Tags: javascript

Такой код

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

$.each(body , function (key){
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].innerHTML = '<p>' + key + '</p>' + '<p>' + 'Price:$' + body[key] + '</p>';
        }
    });
```

let items = document.querySelectorAll('.items'); Класс может находится в разных файлах и областях DOM.

В эту функцию будет приходить объект(json) ключ значение.

Входящий массив объект нужно перебрать и вывести разные значения, как это сделать?

В данный момент выводит последний элемент массива.

Вот разметка

```
<ul class="products">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">
                        <div class="items">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">
                        <div class="items">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">
                        <div class="items">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Чтобы вывести все, вместо innerHTML используйте функцию append

Comment: .innerHTML += такая мелочь, а уже упускается...

Comment: append сбивает event который привязан к DOM. += выводит весь входящий массив в каждый элемент. Нужен вывод в 1 элемент один ключ и одно значение, во второй элемент второй ключ и второе значение  и так в каждый элемент "p" родительского класса .items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const jsn = [{'key':'aaa','price':100},{'key':'bbb','price':200},{'key':'zzz','price':300}];

let items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

items.forEach((item, index) =>{
  item.innerHTML = '<p>' + jsn[index].key + '</p>' + '<p>' + 'Price:$' + jsn[index].price + '</p>'
})
```

```html
<ul class="products">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">
                        <div class="items">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">
                        <div class="items">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">
                        <div class="items">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Отличный пример. А если такой массив {
  "ручка": "10",
  "карандаш": "5",
  "точилка": "8"
}

Comment: Точно так же, только добавляете 3 поля, а не два.